# Index.html not generated after npm run build with VueJS + Vite

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vite

I am currently working on an application using VueJS launched with Vite. I am at the point where I need to run `npm run build`. The issue is that when doing so, there is no `index.html` file created in the dist folder and I am not sure that all the necessary files are successfully built as well (some images are missing in the dist folder).

You can see below the file structure of my app (node_modules folder is not listed) :

```
|   .env
|   .env.dev
|   .env.prod
|   .eslintrc.cjs
|   .gitignore
|   index.html
|   package-lock.json
|   package.json
|   README.md
|   tree.txt
|   vite.config.js
|   
+---public
|   |   favicon.ico
|   |   
|   \---img
|       \---cards
|               ssbm.jpg
|               ssbu.jpg
|               
\---src
    |   App.vue
    |   main.js
    |   
    +---assets
    |   |   base.css
    |   |   logo.svg
    |   |   
    |   +---datatable
    |   |       down-arrow.png
    |   |       equal.png
    |   |       new.png
    |   |       up-arrow.png
    |   |       
    |   \---menu
    |           menu.png
    |           
    +---components
    |   |   Chart.vue
    |   |   DataTable.vue
    |   |   Home.vue
    |   |   LineChart.vue
    |   |   ListCompletion.vue
    |   |   Menu.vue
    |   |   Ranking.vue
    |   |   Seeding.vue
    |   |   Test.vue
    |   |   
    |   \---icons
    |           IconCommunity.vue
    |           IconDocumentation.vue
    |           IconEcosystem.vue
    |           IconSupport.vue
    |           IconTooling.vue
    |           
    \---router
            index.js
```

And below the file structure of the dist folder after running `npm run build` :

```
|   favicon.ico
|   tree.txt
|   
+---assets
|       main.791974cd.js
|       main.ff39c5a3.css
|       vendor.872756e4.js
|       
\---img
    \---cards
            ssbm.jpg
            ssbu.jpg
```

Moreover, here is my `vite.config.js` file :

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "url";

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

const env = process.env.VITE_APP_ENV || 'dev';
const envConfig = dotenv.config({ path: `.env.${env}` }).parsed;

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  define: {
    'process.env': Object.keys(envConfig).reduce((acc, key) => {
      acc[key] = envConfig[key];
      return acc;
    }, {}),
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
  build: {
    outDir: 'dist',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: 'src/main.js'
    }
  }
});
```

I do not know if I am doing something wrong here but in any case thank you in advance.

Comment: the index.html must store in 'public' folder and then build project

Comment: @hamidmokhtari it is Vue 3; opposite Vue 2 (Webpack), the index file should be in the root directory. https://vitejs.dev/guide/#index-html-and-project-root

Comment: I am using Vue 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need custom build behaviour, please drop the `build` option from the `vite.config.js` file. It forces vite to use the default `rollupOptions` configs.

As a solution, you need to add the `index.html` file as another input.

```js
// vite.config.js

  build: {
    outDir: 'dist',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: ['src/main.js', './index.html']
    }
  }
```